# Reading specific line in file with unknown index using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have an IN file that looks as below.

```
;**********  Information  **********
;Date=190303
;Class_1=US13091990#1Joyce#2Female
;Phone_Number=98233215.00
;School=St.Joseph\JuniorHighSchool
;ID=F1
;***********************************
```

I want to read the specific line, for the example  I want to read `Class_1`. But the index of the `Class_1` keeping in mind that the index is dynamic and might change.

```
$File = Get-Content .\file_input
$File = Select-String "Class_1"
$File
```

Comment: take a look at the `Select-String` cmdlet. it will returr the line that contains whatever pattern you give it. [*grin*]

Comment: so, now that you are using `Select-String` ... what is NOT as you need it to be? that code [unfortunately reusing the same $Var] should have the desired line it the `$File` variable.

Comment: Select-String uses RegularExpressions for the pattern, so try `(Select-String -Path '.\file_input' -Pattern "(?<=Class_1=).*").Matches.Value` which uses a [lookbehind](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to worry about where it appears in the file. Leverage the strength of `ConvertFrom-StringData` here. It converts a list of key value pairs into a hashtable.

1. Read in the file.
2. Filter semicolons, double up backslashes (as it is seen as an escape sequence later) and ignore record boundaries.
3. Store as a single string and pass to `ConvertFrom-StringData`
4. Convert to PowerShell object

---

```
$filteredContent = (Get-Content "c:\temp\file_input") -replace '^;' -replace '\\','\\' | Where-Object{-not $_.startswith('*')} 
$information = [pscustomobject]($filteredContent -join "`r`n" | ConvertFrom-StringData)
$information.class_1
```

So using the above, this is what `$information` would look like.

```
Class_1      : US13091990#1Joyce#2Female
School       : St.Joseph\JuniorHighSchool
Date         : 190303
Phone_Number : 98233215.00
ID           : F1
```

This would also make dealing with more of these records easier and give you more flexibility if you need to do more post processing.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like the following to read your INI file and select the line that contains Class_*number*:

```
$a = Get-Content ini.ini
$data = $a | Select-String -Pattern "Class_\d+"
```

From there, you can use `$data` to access different parts of the line. See below for some examples:

```
$NumberAfterUnderscore = ($data.matches.value -split "_")[1]
$DataAfterEqualSign = ($data -split "=")[1]
$DataBetweenEqualandPound = (($data -split "=")[1] -split "#")[0]
$DataBetweenFirstandSecondPounds = (($data -split "=")[1] -split "#")[1]
$DataAfterLastPound = (($data -split "=")[1] -split "#")[2]
```

Here are the outputs from the code above:

```
$NumberAfterUnderscore
1

$DataAfterEqualSign
US13091990#1Joyce#2Female

$DataBetweenEqualandPound
US13091990

$DataBetweenFirstandSecondPounds
1Joyce

$DataAfterLastPound
2Female

$data.matches.value
Class_1
```

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

As suggested here is the code again with some comments. 
I also edited part of the code to further explain how to get the individual values of the parameters in the file.

```
   foreach($line in Get-Content .\file_input) { #Loop though each line of the file
        if ($line.Contains("=") { #If the line contains "=" then we know that the line contains a parameter
            $splittedLine = $line.Split("=") #We know that the parameter line can be split at "=" to get parameter type and value of parameter
            $type = $splittedLine[0] #First part of line contains the type
            switch($type) { #Lets switch on the type to handle each type accordingly
                ";Date"{ #Here we have the Date type
                    $date = $splittedLine[1]
                }
                ";Class_1"{ #Here we have the Class_1 type
                    $class1 = $splittedLine[1]
                }
                ";Phone_Number"{ #Here we have the Phone_Number type
                    $phoneNum = $splittedLine[1]
                }
                ";School"{ #Here we have the School type
                    $school = $splittedLine[1]
                }
                ";ID"{ #Here we have the ID type
                    $id = $splittedLine[1]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Point taken. I added further explanation.

Answer (score 1):

the object returned from using `Select-String` is a MatchInfo object. that may be giving you problems when trying to use the result as a string. here's one way to handle that ... and to parse the output into $vars.

you may prefer to parse the line into a PSCustomObject. if you have problems with that and want some help with it, please ask. [*grin*]

the code ...

```
# fake reading in a text file
#    in real life, use Get-Content
$InStuff = @'
;**********  Information  **********
;Date=190303
;Class_1=US13091990#1Joyce#2Female
;Phone_Number=98233215.00
;School=St.Joseph\JuniorHighSchool
;ID=F1
;***********************************
'@ -split [environment]::NewLine

$ThingToFind = 'Class_1'

$FoundString = $InStuff |
    Select-String -SimpleMatch $ThingToFind

# Select-String returns a MatchInfo object,
#    so it needs to be converted to a regular string before using it as such
$ID_Number, $Name, $Gender = $FoundString.ToString().Split('=')[1].Split('#')
$Name = $Name.Trim('1')
$Gender = $Gender.Trim('2')


$FoundString.ToString()
$ID_Number
$Name
$Gender
```

output ...

```
;Class_1=US13091990#1Joyce#2Female
US13091990
Joyce
Female
```

Answer (score -1):

You can tell your program that if it found `Class_1` in the script pick up the data after the `=`.